# Unable to view videoview in realtime database using firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I want to view `VideoView` in `RecyclerView`. I am able to get the Uri of the uploaded videos but I am unable to play that video in the `VideoView`. I have checked that the I am getting the correct link of the video.

Here is my adapter code:

```
class VideoAdapter(private var mContext: Context,private var mvideos: List<VID>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.videos_adapter, parent, false)return ViewHolder(view)}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val videoid = mvideos[position]

    holder.vidId.text = videoid.getilp()

    val mediaController = MediaController(mContext)
    mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.videoIv)
    holder.videoIv.setMediaController(mediaController)
    holder.videoIv.setVideoURI(videoid.getVideoUrl().toUri())
    holder.videoIv.requestFocus()
    holder.videoIv.start()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mvideos.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var videoIv: VideoView = itemView.videos_ret
    var vidId: TextView = itemView.videos_id_ret
}

}
```

I tried to use this adapter to get videos in `VideoView` but it is not playing any video.

Comment: So you say that `videoid.getVideoUrl().toUri()` returns the correct value?

Comment: getVideoUrl() gives me the link. For setmediaUri I convert it to URI. I checked it's value in textview.